# Pandas Mapping Multiple Column Function on a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, geospatial

So I have a pandas dataframe containing column fields 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' and I would like to map a function that would take those two fields as well as a precision that would be applied to an entire dataframe, and add the column 'GEOHASH' to the frame with the output of the function being mapped.

Right now I've only been able to implement a hackish string concatenation then having the mapped function parse out the args appropriately. At the very least it shows you output I'm  looking for.

What I have currently:

```
def my_encode(argstring):
    argstring = str.split(argstring,'_')
     lat,long,precision = float(argstring[0]),float(argstring[1]),int(argstring[2])
    try:
        hash = geohash.encode(lat,long,precision)
    except:
        hash = ''
    return hash

precision = 7
data['ARGS'] = data['Latitude'].astype(str) + '_' + data['Longitude'].astype(str) + '_' + str(precision)
data['HASH'] = data['ARGS'].map(my_encode)
```

Its not terrible but I think a more appropriate solution probably exists. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may consider putting a sample dataset and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
data['HASH'] = data.apply(lambda x: geohash.encode(x.Latitude, x.Longitude, precision), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

(I modified the function because I don't have geohash)

```
def my_encode(argstring):
    argstring = str.split(argstring,'_')
    lat,long,precision = float(argstring[0]),float(argstring[1]),int(argstring[2])
    try:
        hsh = np.max([lat,long,precision])
    except:
        hsh = ''
    return hsh
```

---

```
print( data )

   Latitude  Longitude
A        10          5
B        10         10
C        10         15
D        10         20
```

---

```
precision = 7
data['ARGS'] = data['Latitude'].astype(str) + '_' + data['Longitude'].astype(str) + '_' + str(precision)
data['HASH'] = data['ARGS'].apply(my_encode)
print( data )

   Latitude  Longitude     ARGS  HASH
A        10          5   10_5_7  10.0
B        10         10  10_10_7  10.0
C        10         15  10_15_7  15.0
D        10         20  10_20_7  20.0
```